# code is not working from second if statement?

Tags: python

Arpasland has surrounded by attackers. A truck enters the city. The driver claims the load is food and medicine from Iranians. Ali is one of the soldiers in Arpasland. He doubts about the truck, maybe it's from the siege. He knows that a tag is valid if the sum of every two consecutive digits of it is even and its letter is not a vowel. Determine if the tag of the truck is valid or not.

We consider the letters "A","E","I","O","U","Y" to be vowels for this problem.

Input Format

The first line contains a string of length 9. The format is "DDXDDD-DD", where D stands for a digit (non zero) and X is an uppercase english letter.

Output Format

Print "valid" (without quotes) if the tag is valid, print "invalid" otherwise (without quotes)

`code` i write:

```
x=input()
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    x1=x[i]
    x2=x[i+1]
    j=list()
    j.append(x1)
    j.append(x2)
    print(j)
    j1="".join(j)
    print(j1)
    print(j1.isdigit())
    print(j1[0],j1[1])
    if(j1.isdigit()):
        if(((j1[0]+j1[1])%2)!=0):
            print("invalid")
            break
        else:
            conitnue
    elif('A,E,I,O,U,Y,-'.find(y)!=-1 or 'A E I O U Y'.find(x)!=-1):
        continue
    else:
        print("invalid ")
        break
print("valid")
```

i am getting the `error` message at second `if` condition line
My `error` messege is `not all argument are converted during string formatting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `(((j1[0]+j1[1])%2)!=0)`, both `j1[0]` and `j1[1]` are strings while you're using them as if they were integers. Cast them to integers using `int` and you should be good; i.e. check that `(((int(j1[0]) + int(j1[1])) % 2) != 0)` instead.

Concretely, what's going on is that if, say, `j1 = ['8', '9']`, then `j1[0] + j1[1]` is the string `'89'`. When you apply `%` on a string, what's happening behind the scenes is that Python is trying to apply its string formatting to your inputs, which isn't possible here. That is, `'f%d' % 2` would give you the string `'f2'`, but `'89' % 2` is impossible, and leads to the error you've described.

```py
In [5]: j1 = ['8', '9']

In [6]: j1[0] + j1[1]
Out[6]: '89'

In [7]: 'f%d' % 2
Out[7]: 'f2'

In [8]: (j1[0] + j1[1]) % 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-69ab5a8355ef> in <module>
----> 1 (j1[0] + j1[1]) % 2

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

In [9]: (int(j1[0]) + int(j1[1])) % 2
Out[9]: 1
```

Comment: Explained very well , specially behind the scene paragraph @fuglede, thank you sir !

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer useful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).